# Only open Jupyter lab cell output view

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I was recently introduced to JupyterLab and I have seen this video from the documentation, where they introduce the synchronised "output view" of a cell: 
https://youtu.be/Asa_ML45HP8

I wonder if it was possible to have "only" this output view as the result of executing a script. So that I could run a Python script, and a browser window would open up and I would see only the output view without the Jupyter interface itself.

1. Is this or something similar easily feasible already? E.g. by configuring JupyterLab in some way and then starting it?
2. If I wanted to write an application that does that, do you have hints on where to start from? I presume, that there is a lot of code already present that could be reused.